# How to configure 2 network interfaces which make use of the same physical ethernet port?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, interface

I currently have a linux system with only one physical ethernet port. This physical port has the `eth0` network interface attached to it. I want to create another ethernet interface which also makes use of this single physical port. How could I achieve this using the `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

My ultimate goal is to be able to access two different networks using a single ethernet port. For example, if I have the following `interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.11
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.16.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.16.1
```

I would expect to be able to ping both networks, but so far I can only ping `eth0` even if I am pinging `eth1` from the right network (192.168.16.0/24). I am sure I am missing some sort of configuration since it would seem too easy to simply add a new entry in the `interfaces` file and hope that it magically works.

I am aware that I can add multiple IPs to a single ethernet interface using the command `ip addr add 192.168.16.100/24 dev eth0` but I would very much prefer to have two separate interfaces.

Thanks!

Comment: `eth0` and `eth1` are separate physical interfaces. Have you looked into creating a virtual interface on one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of a physical port and the Ethernet controller behind it *is* a (physical) interface. You can list the interfaces available with `ip link`. To have more than one interface, you will have to add a network card or a USB Ethernet adapter.